# What is correct? “durée du séjour” vs. “durée de séjour”

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles, de

What is right here? or is both equally fine?

Intuitively I'd say:

> durée du sejour.

meant is the length of a stay (in a hotel or hostel or hospital or whatever).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it refers to a specific stay/visit you should use “durée du séjour” as *du* is the combination of a preposition (*de*) and a definite article (*le*).

> Nous serons à votre disposition pendant toute la durée du séjour.

If you want to express stay/visit length in general, use “durée de séjour”.

> La durée de séjour moyenne dans notre hotel est de 5 jours.

You can sometimes use either (in a form for example). But in the examples provided above you could not exchange one for the other.

Comment: Good examples you gave to explain the difference.

Comment: In my opinion, the first example may not be correct. A more idiomatic way to say this is : "Nous serons à votre disposition pendant toute la durée de votre séjour".

Also, I think the second example may be misleading, as I can't see why "La durée moyenne du séjour dans notre hotel est de 5jours".

Comment: The first example is definitely correct. I'm not saying it should be used in all contexts. As for the last one, you changed the word order and *séjour* can in this case be used with a definite article because of the complement *dans notre hotel*, but meaningwise it's a bit off because it's odd to speak about averages if you identify a single kind of *séjour*. I think your comment is more misleading than the example itself. But you're right I could remove *dans notre hotel* completely to make it even clearer.